# objective c: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: objective-c, animation, core-animation, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I have an Image that I want to dangle back and forth (once) around a fixed point. So I have the following code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
myDial.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(45)); //lineA
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
myDial.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(0 )); //lineB
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

What happens when I run the above code is that lineA gets executed immediately (and not in 1.5 seconds). Right after that lineB gets executed in 1.5seconds. I want both animations to take 1.5 seconds each. How can I do this

Comment: It looks like you have animation duration and animation delay mixed up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to have two UIView animations together to create one visual animation, you could just use Core Animation and do it all in one animation. Using Core Animation you can tell the animation to automatically reverse (go to 45 degrees during 1.5 seconds and then back again during the same duration) and you won't have to care about timing the two animations together. You could do it like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
[rotate setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[rotate setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:degreesToRadians(45)]];
[rotate setDuration:1.5];
[rotate setAutoreverses:YES]; // go back the same way
[rotate setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[myDial layer] addAnimation:rotate forKey:@"dangleMyDial"];
```

---

If you haven't imported QuartzCore.framework into your project and imported the , you'll need to do so for Core Animation to work.

Comment: I had placed the following:     [self performSelector:@selector(reverseRotate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5]; 
after the first animation, where the method "reverseRotate" contains the second animation. Its working perfectly. I have tested your code and it also works great. Better than creating separate method for the second animation

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to execute the next animation sequence in the completion function.

I have tested this code. I take the liberation to change the number around a bit so that it looks more like a telephone dial.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0 delay: 0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    myDial.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rect.transform, M_PI / 4); 
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.7 delay: 0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        myDial.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } completion: nil];
}];
```

Comment: Mhh, how would I use animationDelay with my code there. I need the first animation to complete in 1.5seconds and then the second animation to come right after and also take 1.5seconds

Comment: yeh I have tried doing that. Animation1 still takes place immediately (in a flash) and 1.5 seconds later animation2 takes place (taking 1.5seconds to complete as required).

Comment: @nhahtdh When you say "really doesn't work", do you set the delay as `[UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];` or do you remember that you _need_ to set the delay from the current time? Like this: `[UIView setAnimationDelay:CACurrentMediaTime() + 2.0];`

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: Just to be clear, the method that "doesn't work" is based on the OP's code. I use the first one in your comment to set the animation delay to the 2nd animation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, I think I see your problem. The `setAnimationDuration` does not delay the animation's start; rather, it tells the animation how long to complete. If you are in fact trying to delay the start of your animation, look into using a `NSTimer` in order to do so. (Or using the setAnimationDelay method). Set up a `NSTimer`that runs the first "rotation", waits until it is finished, and then runs the second, either by calling another `NSTimer`or by using a loop.

Comment: I have a dial,  and I want it to rotate 45 degrees in 1.5seconds. Right after that I want it to return to original position (0degrees) in 1.5seconds. But with the code I have written the second animation does not wait for the first one to complete. Instead the first animation takes place immediately and the second one then takes 1.5 seconds from the 45degree position to returning back to 0degrees

Comment: You could try using both `setAnimationDelay`and the `NSTimer`. Setup the first animation to run right away, and then use either a timer or the animation delay to delay the second animation to 1.5 s. So, it would rotate to 45 in 1.5 s, and then the second animation would kick in as soon as it is done. If one way doesn't work quite right, try the other.